# Getting Artifactory Logs from JFrog hosted service

Tags: artifactory

Our JFrog Artifactory repo is intermittently sending 403 errors when requesting deb packages from our repos. Systems experiencing this will automatically retry after a few minutes and successfully download the package. It is always the same package, and there are many systems which successfully download the package on the first try.

We are attempting to troubleshoot this. However, when trying to create a support bundle to examine the logs, the API returns a 405 Method Not Allowed. There are no other avenues for downloading logs except the live log view, which by definition is only forward looking (e.g. the issue would have to happen sometime in the future while watching the logs via the live viewer to see any errors).

Is there some way to get access to our Artifactory logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can track some of the logs in the administration section.

Administration -> Artifactory -> System logs.

Are the 403 coming during a special peak of usage (high loads)?

Comment: Thanks; It seems like the 403s only happen when I don't watch the logs :) Seriously, they seem to happen overnight, but I wouldn't say there is an abnormal traffic. That link you suggest is a link only to live output. Somehow in the last 24 hours I've lost the ability to even download the contents. So Basically I need to watch this log and wait for a client to trip on a 403 and quickly cut-n-paste the output to see it. Not ideal, so I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere. Yesterday I at least had a download link for what had been live captured; today that link is gone.